# Partially selected checkbox on Android?

Tags: android, checkbox, selection

On Android, I need a checkbox (or checkbox-like component) which can represent/control a flag for a number of selected items. There are 3 possibilities which I need to represent:

1. Flag is set for all items.
2. Flag is set for none of the items.
3. Flag is set for some of the items.

I'm imagining something like this:

[image]

If the user selects the checkbox when it's in state 3, it will switch to state 1. Thereafter, it will only toggle between states 1 & 2.

If you're familiar with the checkboxes in the attributes section of the file properties dialog in Windows, that's what I'm after.

**Is there a native Android UI widget, or an existing open-source widget, which can do this?**

I'm fairly confident I could do my own implementation, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel!

Comment: check [this](http://code.google.com/p/ull-etsii-geobloc/wiki/ThreeStateCheckBox), looks like what you want

Comment: @nandeesh Thanks, doesn't look too far off although their extra state is 'crossed' which is something I would need to change. I might use it as a reference if I have to do my own implementation.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/maydin/gdgankandroidcomps/wiki/Half-Check-Box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd be best of with your own implementation. And it will be a fairly simple one, just use the: setOnCheckedChangeListener,  here is a simple tutorial that just shows the use of this listeners, you will just implement changing your flags, and setting some of your checkboxes checkable when in the correct state.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

hope it helps!

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I think this is a valid answer. Android doesn't provide this so you will either make your own, or find a 3rd party solution.

Comment: I think I'm coming to the same conclusion - ie. I'll need to do my own implementation. If this winds up being the only option, I'll try to get the implementation details posted here for others to use. By the way, the downvote wasn't from me!

Comment: I dont understand the downvote either. So I'm upvoting cause this is a  valid answer.

Comment: Making own implementation is simple, but making it look and feel like native Android checkbox on different platforms - is not.